# knockout.js bind string value to function

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[JSFiddle source](http://jsfiddle.net/M8KFd/700/)
I use `hello.bind('Hi!!!')`
but inside method `hello` i get view-model Object instead of string value. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your markup to:

```
<button data-bind="click: hello.bind($data, 'Hi!!!')">Say hello</button>
```

From the documentation:

`Alternatively, if you prefer to avoid the function literal in your view, you can use the bind function, which attaches specific parameter values to a function reference.`  More on bind can be found at [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).